# Scrollbars on CSS blocks

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am very new to CSS.
I have some wishes for scrollbars.

In my example (see code below) I have two independent blocks side by side. 
Think of the rectangles as being images.

So far I have got:

I have got a **vertical** scrollbar for the left pink rectangles in block (“navigation”).

I have got a **horizontal** scrollbar at the bottom of the page window (which is good) for the large cyan rectangle in block (“content”). But it does **not** work good, cannot scroll to the right side of the cyan image.

Tested in Chrome and IE.

Here is an image of the html page at http://arxfoto.se/ScrollbarTest.html 
(see http://arxfoto.se/scrollbartest.jpg).

I would like to have a **horizontal** scrollbar for the left pink  “navigation” block at the bottom of the page window.

I would like to have a **vertical** scrollbar for the cyan “content” block, at the right edge of the page window. Hm, I just noticed that the scroll wheel on the mouse performs this vertical scrolling! But that is a bit hidden..?

I would like to have a **better horizontal** scrollbar for the “content” block.

.

Is this at all possible in CSS?

.

Any help is very much appreciated!!

.

Code  (see http://arxfoto.se/ScrollbarTest.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Scrollbar test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:0 10px 0 10px;
        height:100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #content {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 210px;
        display:block;
        background:white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border:1px solid #888;
        position:fixed;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #navigation {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
        display:block;
        background:lightgrey;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:170px;
        height: 100%;
        border:1px solid #888;
        position:fixed; 
        overflow: auto;
    }

* html #content {position:absolute;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;Vertical scrollbar!<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Wanted:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Horizontal scrollbar
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;at the bottom<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;of browser window</div><br>
<div style="width:250px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;A wider image.</div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;"></div><br>
<div style="width:170px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;background:pink;">
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Last image.</div><br>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div style="width:1500px;height:1000px;border:1px solid #000;background:cyan;">
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a large image.
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wanted:
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vertical and (better) horizontal scrollbar for this block, 
on the edges of the browser window.
<br><br>
<h1>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
9&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
10
</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bottom of image</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add overflow attribute to both the div like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height: 100vh
    }
    #navigation {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background:lightgrey;
        width:25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #888;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    #content {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background:white;
        width: 74%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #888;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 10px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
</style>
```

Link for HTML Page - https://68wgy.csb.app/

Comment: Thank you so much! ! !   I put your changes into my code and also  made the left pane fixed. See http://arxfoto.se/Scrollbartest_2.html . But I got an ugly right margin field with a non-active vertical scrollbar at the right edge. Is it possible to get rid of that margin too?

Comment: it's because you have added the border to both div **#navigation** and **#content** and using 100vh as height if you add `box-sizing: border-box` to both id you will get rid of the right side bar

Comment: #navigation {
       .
       .
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

Comment: Thanks for your very great patience! ! !   Your changes have been applied to http://arxfoto.se/ScrollbarTest_3.html . The result is really good! The right edge bar is gone, fine!  The right margin field is still there, but  it is very much OK!  One small issue: This looks nice in IE11: grey scrollbars, arrows in the ends.   But in Chrome v83… slightly worse: Black scrollbars, no arrows.   
Which is OK with me, because it does work.  But I am getting a little bit curious – do you know if there is a reason why Chrome reacts as it does? Can you do anything about it?

Comment: We have disabled the default property of scrollbar and created a newly customized one if you want to add the arrow to you can add it by yourself using `::-webkit-scrollbar-button`. You can get a more detailed idea about refer to this [article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Comment: StackOverflow, Amit Kumar and others – I am so grateful for all help! Thank you!!